# Schema.rb doesn't include table that exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, schema, database-migration

I've run all of my migrations and my schema.rb does not include a "create table" line for table that clearly should exist. The table actually shows up in the rails console too, when I access it via its corresponding ActiveRecord class.

Any ideas why this might be happening? And what the consequences of this discrepancy in the schema could have moving forward? The project appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your schema.rb to mirror the database with this command.

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

Schema.rb is not used in development or production so it has no effect on a running application. However it is used when setting up the test database. Can read about it more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you